# Run CSS animation only once

Tags: html, css

I have the following CSS snippet which is used to animate / move some label text when a user selects an input box.

```
input:focus ~ label, input.used ~ label {
    top: -20px;
    transform: scale(.75); left: -2px;
    color: #4a89dc;
}
```

This works fine but I'm facing an issue. when I select a different input, the label text animates back into place and overlaps the old text.

I would either want the label text to disappear all together or I would want it to remain in it's new position. In other words, It should not return to it's inactive position.

Comment: try to create a js fiddle or post some more code here for testing.

Comment: That was correct. I did so and issue is taken care of. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The only answer to this is to add a class to the element and then on the new class do xyz.

Example would be to use jQuery:

```
$('label').on('focus',function(){
    $(this).addClass('theClass');
});
```

Once you've got the class on there you can tell the element to do as you wish:

```
.theClass {
    top:-20px;
}
```

This will keep your element -20px. You could do this with vanilla js:

```
document.getElementById('label').addEventListener('focus', function () {
 if (this.classList.contains('item')) {
     this.classList.add('item-off');
  } 
});
```

You'd have to add item class to your label.

Comment: Does it really worth to include jQuery for such a trivial problem?

Comment: Without javascript there isn't anyway to determine if the user has been to the element. You could do it with native js, but jQuery simple enough and is included in most projects now.